# Is it possible to create an installer that includes ms sql express? (wihtout separate exe)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, setup-project

Is it possible to create an installer that includes ms sql express?

I currently install ms sql express via setting the setup project's pre-requisites.  It outputs 2 files, an msi and a setup.exe.  The setup.exe will detect is SQL express is installed and install it.  It works great.  But now I have to distribute 2 files...

I'd like to combine everything inside the .msi.  is that possible?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535966/merge-msi-and-exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pack them both in a self-extracting zip file (.exe file extension) that runs setup after extract.

Comment: Yes, e.g. using `iexpress.exe` that comes with Windows.