# Edit fileInfo of exe created using Iexpress by modifying sed file

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, sed, iexpress

I have been able to merge my .msi and exe files to a single exe file using the IExpress wizard and been able to install the  exe on target machines without any issues.

While i noticed the FileInformation of the exe file created using the IExpress tool , i noticed one thing that the few properties are by default like Product Name , Company name ,File Description, Copyright etc . They are using default values like Internet Explorer, Microsoft etc and can we edit these values?

Some research shows that editing sed files will help to fix this issue , and i editted the sed file by adding an extra section like this by opening on notepad

```
VersionInfo=VersionSection
[VersionSection]
Internalname=My.exe
OriginalFilename=mytest.exe
FileDescription=%FileDesc%
CompanyName=MyComp
ProductName=MyComp-App
LegalCopyright=@C 2015
[Strings]
FileDesc="My lovely description"
```

Saved the notepad and opened the exe , but changes are not reflecting .
How can i do it properly ? Also do i need to share this sed file also with end users to see the proper FileInfo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the IExpress command to your post-build step.

Here is a screenshot of a project showing the packaging order if you're also going to sign your deliverables.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the SED the first time is to let IExpress generate a new one.  The first screen of IExpress creates a new Self Extracting Directive (SED) file, or edits an existing one.  Create a new one just the first time.

Then edit your SED file, then run IExpress again, this time clicking on Open then the 'Browse' button to find the SED file you just edited.

On the 'Next' screen you again must select to 'Modify' the SED file you just created.  After that, you can just click next to repeat all the options you set the first time, and the newly generated executable will now show the results of the recent edits to the SED file.