# Is it possible to create self-extracted setup with InstallShield Limited Edition

Tags: installation, installshield-le

InstallShield Limited Edition comes as free addition to Visual Studio 2010 users. It has many options on how to configure installation package, but I am having an issue to figure out if is possible to create a self-extracting setup with LE. Alternative to this can be [7-zip SFX add-on](http://www.7zsfx.info/en/), NSIS, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've since imaged a new dev machine and installed InstallShield 2010LE.  Through the standard Visual Studio (solution) Configuration Manager you have the choice of build CD-ROM, DVD-5 and Single Image ( self extracting EXE ).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have notice that as well, but was having problem with generating any output for Single Image. Can you provide any help on how to get this output.

Comment: Right click the solution and select Configuration Manager.  Then change the active solution configurate to single image.  When you build the solution it will build the single image solution configuration which will then in turn build your projects single image project configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Windows's own `IExpress.exe` can also be used for **[creating a self-extracting installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535966/merge-msi-and-exe/536044#536044)**.

Comment: I think I had some issues with IExpress in the past, like if SFX was created by XP version of IExpress then it will throw error on Win98. Although I am not sure what will happen with setup build by InstallShield LE on Win98.

Comment: Are you really still supporting Win98? That's pretty hard to do if you use current tools.

Comment: I've worked at a lot of companies over the years and you'd be suprised how much PowerBuilder, Delphi, VB6 and what not is still being used out there.

Answer (score -3):

I don't have InstallShield LE 2010 installed on this machine so it's hard to answer.  Why don't you install it and find out?   My guess is InstallShield supports this.  If anything it might not support an uncompressed MSI in order to try to prevent you from coloring outside of the lines.

Or you could just call them.  Worst that will happen is you'll get spam from them trying to get you to upgrade.