# How to create a single setup.exe with InstallShield limited edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-le

I am trying to create a single .exe file installer. I managed to get all the dependencies in to a .exe file (by setting extract from Setup.exe property). How do i get the .msi also inside the setup.exe file?

This is what it looks like now

[image]

Comment: Why not skip the `setup.exe` altogether and just distribute the MSI file? You could call it `setup.msi` if you prefer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had this trouble too. The way it does is very unintuitive, IMO.

1. Highlight the Set up project
2. On Visual Studio Standard toolbar, choose "Solution Configuration" dropdown. Probably it is selected as "Debug". Change it to "Single Image"

   [image]
3. Right click on your setup project and Build.

It should create a single setup.exe.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  I have an Install Shield project that produces a Disk Image and I want instead to produce a single click solution.  However when I select my Install Project the only options in the Solutions Configuration pull down in the toolbar are Release and Debug.  If I open the Configuration Manager the only options there for my Install Project under Configuration are Release and Debug.  I'm running VS2013.

Comment: How do I get the Single Image option to appear?

Answer (score 9):

I don't have InstallShield LE installed on the machine in front of me but my memory is that it has different solution configurations defined.  One of them is called SingleImage.  Just build that release.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a stand-alone setup.exe with InstallShield LE is just a little tricky. You have to remember several things.

1. Go to "Build" -> "Configuration Manager" -> change the configuration to "SingleImage."  You may have access to the configuration directly on the tool bar at the top.  Your options will be "CDROM", "DVD-5", an "SingleImage."  You can change it from the configuration manager or using the tool bar.
2. Next go to "Prepare for release" in the solution explorer (on the far right) and double-click on "Releases."  On the left-hand side you will see your "Builds" tree.  Work your way down the tree to "SingleImage."   Click on it.
3. In the middle witll be three tabs: "Build", "Setup.exe", "Signing."  Click on "Setup.exe."   Set Setup Launcher to Yes (it will probably already be set to this).  Down at the end of the options is a section called "InstallShield Prerequisites Location" - set this to "Extract From Setup.exe" otherwise any prerequisites (there are usually lots) will not be embedded into the setup.exe.

You're done.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Releases option.
2. Releases configuration tab will open on left-hand side.
3. Expand Default Configuration
4. Select the configuration which you are using to build the project(Debug/Release)
5. Right click the configuration and select release Wizard.
   Click next button till you get Release Configuration Screen.
6. Select first option Compress all files.
7. Click next till you find the Summary page and click on finish

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a single setup.exe file with IExpress.exe which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535966/merge-msi-and-exe/536044#536044)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the solution configuration properties and configure as shown in the image:

[image: configuration]